# How do I get the country code of the user

Tags: jquery

In my JSP I am sending some user information to my controller. Depending on the user's market I need to change my workflow in my Spring controller, so I am sending location tags. The code I'm using is:

```
var languageObject = window.navigator.userLanguage || window.navigator.language;
// language Object will contain a string like "en-US"
var userInfo = languageObject.split('-');

var user_market = userInfo[1].toUpperCase(); //macOS might use lowercase
var user_language = userInfo[0];
```

However, after reading up on the web docs for this, it's possible for the `languageObject` to only contain the language, not the country code. For example it may only return `en` not `en-US`.

Is there a way to fetch the country code in case the `window.language` object doesn't contain that info?

Comment: There's no reliable way to do what you're trying, for the reason you have discovered. You could potentially use an IP lookup service, but this is not generally free (depending on the volume of calls you need to make) and is also not 100% accurate. The best way is to ask the user.

Comment: If this needs to be done securely it should be done in the controller, not the client. The user can override anything that's done in the client.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan As this is an enterprise app, there will be plenty of calls, so I'm avoiding ip lookup services.  However, I want this to be a seamless application, so maybe I can ask the team I'm consuming to make the country code ignorable during serialization and do something else

Comment: @Barmar Good point!  The JSP page is rendered from a redirect from my controller, and I'm already grabbing IP address in my controller before redirecting to the JSP, so maybe I can capture it there

Comment: As the previous comment said. But `navigator.languages` (plural!) will give you more than `navigator.language` In other words you could get (ok, unreliably but...) more data to clue. I.e: I use my browser and language settings to `en` but here's what Chrome reveals on my machine for my preferred languages: `["en", "en-US", "hr"]` (see the `hr`? Could it be valuable?) Same as many people, they keep their OS in `en` (habit or other reasons) but there's certainly other valuable info. I'd do: if both the second and third keys don't hold the `en` string than... :)

Comment: @RokoC.Buljan true, I will look into that, thanks!

Comment: You can use services like MaxMind to convert IP address to location. While it's not perfectly accurate, country codes are generally reliable.